# Can Invoke-Command access to files on remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I see that `Invoke-Command` can run inline script blocks or a local script but I was wondering if there is anyway to use `Invoke-Command`, or some other PowerShell command to run a script which resides on a remote server?

The issue is that the script we have relies on modules as well and it's not clear how `Invoke-Command` works if there are dependent modules.

As an example, we have a script Deploy-OurApp.ps1, which sets up our application for use via Remote Desktop. This script relies on an OurApp.psm1 module. Currently both reside in the same directory on the server, so running the script is not an issue, but we have to log in remotely.

I'm not sure we want anyone who is going to be running the script to require all of the .ps1 and psm1 files locally installed.

Comment: `Invoke-command` should be able to do what you're asking for, to include using the modules as long as they're being referenced in the remote script. As an alternative, you can use persistent `sessions` as well.

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName NetBIOSName -ScriptBlock { C:\Script.ps1 }` will run the script that resides on the remote pc and return the output back to yours

Comment: you can import modules inside your `ScriptBlock` as well.. `-ScriptBlock { Import-module xyz; C:\yourScript.ps1 }`.

Comment: Abraham, can you post as an answer? I want to mark it as such.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - I've got seemingly working now, but I don't get anything back. Invoke-Command just returns immediately.